# Nesting a viewmodel inside a Knockout template binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, template-engine

I have a knockout template that is successfully adding content to my page. What I want to have happen is another knockout viewmodel bound inside the template that gets added.

Here's not my best example, but it shows the javascript vividly exploding when you try to add a `text/javascript` node inside a knockout `text/html` template.

http://jsfiddle.net/hYYPr/2/

A less successful approach I tried doesn't even execute the javascript inside when the template gets added to the DOM.

Any ideas or examples for how to pull off something similar? Or another approach entirely?

Comment: I don't know why you want to do this, but I really don't think this is a good idea. I definitely don't think this fits the MVVM pattern (A viewmodel IN THE VIEW!). It's also going to break later when its not spitting out garbage, and you are binding two viewmodels in a single DIV. There will probably be no way around this, as Knockout was not designed to work like that.

Comment: Why not simply bind your subviemdodel to the newly generated HTML?